# iPhone: serialize and send objects over bluetooth?

Tags: iphone, serialization, networking, bluetooth

What is the best way to serialize an object and send it over a bluetooth (or network connection)?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [gamekit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) APIs.

sendDataToAllPeers:withDataMode:error: or

sendData:toPeers:withDataMode:error:

the data can be any format encapsulated in NSData.