# I want to sent data using bluetooth in iphone, how can I?

Tags: iphone, bluetooth

I have saved for NSStrings in database, and after query of select, I have saved them in some array,,

now I want to send that array and save in database of other iphone, via using bluetooth,

what should I do, because as per my knowledge, I can sent NSData via bluetooth,,,

help needed here.....

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174168/iphone-serialize-and-send-objects-over-bluetooth) helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sample project GKTank from apple uses bluetooth for connectivity and NSData as packets. Here's a link:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GKTank/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: GKSession and GKPeerPickerController, These both things I don't want to use, so is there any other way ?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not really familiar with the project's code. I was researching iOS connectivity a while ago and found this.